# Checking for missing operands in a binary expression tree

Tags: java, expression-trees

The purpose of the code is to perform the evaluation of binary expression trees (like the one below).

```
          (+)
      (*)     (2)
  (+)     (-)
 3   4   5   2
```

In the code snippet I have, I am confused about how `if (root.getLeft() == null || root.getRight() == null)` checks for missing operands. If it is a leaf node (operand), will it cause an exception (as the if condition will be true)? I also put the question as a comment in the code near the if-statement.

```java
public float calculateValue(TreeNode root) {
  // Check that the root value is not null
  if (root == null) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Root Node must have a value");
  }
  // If this is a leaf node, it should be a number, so return this
  if (root.getLeft() == null && root.getRight() == null) {
    try {
      return Float.parseFloat(root.getItem().toString()); 
    } catch (NumberFormatException parseError) {
      throw new NumberFormatException("Leaves must be numeric");
    }
  }
  // Validate that we have operands
  if (root.getLeft() == null || root.getRight() == null) {     
    // How does this check for missing operands? If it is a leaf node (operand),
    // will it cause an exception (as the if condition will be true)? 
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Operator missing operands”);
  }
  // Retrieve the operands
  float leftOperand = calculateValue(root.getLeft());
  float rightOperand = calculateValue(root.getRight());
  // Extract the operator
  String operatorString = root.getItem().toString();
  if (operatorString.length() > 1) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid operation!");
  }
  char operator = operatorString.charAt(0);
  // Evaluate the operation
```

Comment: *"how does it check the missing operands? ? If it is a leaf node (operand), will it cause an exception, as the if condition is true?"* Um...yes? Assuming leaf nodes have no left or right siblings, presumably `getLeft` and `getRight` return `null`. And so the code will throw an exception. What is it doing that you don't expect?

Comment: If it is a leaf node, it's supposed to continue executing. If only one leaf node is an operand, it's supposed to throw an exception as we need two lead nodes as operands. I guess? I am rather confused about how it works here...apologize if I haven't explained it very clearly.

Comment: @ user: *"If only one leaf node is an operand, it's supposed to throw an exception as we need two lead nodes as operands."* That's what the code does, because it uses `||` ("OR"). So `if (root.getLeft() == null || root.getRight() == null)` means "If `root.getLeft() == null` OR `root.getRight() == `null` then do the bit in the block (which throws the exception).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below I've got your code up to that if-statement with the comments removed:

```
if (root == null) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Root Node must have a value");
}

if (root.getLeft() == null && root.getRight() == null) {
    try {
       return Float.parseFloat(root.getItem().toString()); 
    } catch (NumberFormatException parseError) {
       throw new NumberFormatException("Leaves must be numeric");
    }
}

if (root.getLeft() == null || root.getRight() == null) {     
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Operator missing operands");
}
```

To answer your question, note that in the case of a leaf node, the second if-statement is true. Thus, it will go through that try-catch and never even execute `if (root.getLeft() == null || root.getRight() == null)`.

Comment: because there is a return in the try block? Thanks for that!

Comment: @user3735871 Now answering your remark, yes, the idea is that once it gets to the try-catch, you'll either do the `return Float.parseFloat...` without problems or throw an Exception, but either way you will not go to the third if-statement.